# Making a element less sensitive to Dragging in script.aculo.us

Tags: javascript, draggable, scriptaculous

script.aculo.us Draggable is firing the event too vigorously. When the user is trying to click, it interprets is as a drag when the mouse has only moved 1 pixel.

How would I add a rule for a particular component that amounted to:

Do not consider it a drag event unless the mouse has moved 10 pixels from the point at which is was pressed down.

Thank you.

```
<div id="drag" style="width:100px; height:100px; background:#fff85d; border:1px solid #333;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   new Draggable('drag', { revert: true });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting a delay on the draggable of 100-200ms and destroying the draggable on mouseup. This way if the button is released within the delay period, nothing happens.

I image it would work something like this (untested):

```
var dd = new Draggable('drag', { revert: true, delay:150 });

document.observe("mouseup", function() {
  dd.destroy() 
});
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more on how you achieve that.

Comment: I've provided an example above. It's been a long time since I did any Prototype/Scriptaculous code. I hope it gets you on the right track.